# Prevent inner transaction from rolling back outer transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, spring-data

I have a somewhat complex transaction which does or does not create many different types of entities. Should it fail to create one of those entities due to a validation error, I'd like to simply catch the ConstraintValidationError and move on (allowing any other entities created in the same transaction to save successfully).

I can do this successfully but the validation error still marks my whole transaction for rollback, which I do not want.

I tried changing the single validating method which causes the ConstraintValidationError to have a:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

to force a new transaction, thinking it would mark only that new, inner transaction for rollback, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

The calling class is marked with a:

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor=ConstraintViolationException.class)
```

but this doesn't help if the ConstraintViolationException is in the called method and I do not wish to add it to the called method.

What's the proper way to do something like this?

(Let me know if code is required -- the example is somewhat complex.)

EDIT (5/26/14):

When I try

```
progration = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW
```

I see no change in the result. This particular log is from a test purposefully trying to save a 'department' entity object with a null description, which would be invalid:

```
11:46:43.599 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'DefaultCourseManager.saveDepartment' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
11:46:43.599 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
11:46:43.599 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@3a90c13c] for JPA transaction
11:46:43.599 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Suspending current transaction, creating new transaction with name [edu.ucdavis.dss.dw.site.DefaultCourseManager.saveDepartment]
11:46:43.600 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@67b355c8] for JPA transaction
11:46:43.600 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - begin
11:46:43.600 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
11:46:43.601 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
11:46:43.601 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - initial autocommit status: true
11:46:43.601 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - disabling autocommit
11:46:43.601 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@388623ad]
11:46:43.601 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'save' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
11:46:43.602 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
11:46:43.602 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@67b355c8] for JPA transaction
11:46:43.602 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
11:46:43.606 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select KeyValue from SurrogateKeys where TableName = 'Departments' for update
11:46:43.608 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into SurrogateKeys(TableName, KeyValue) values('Departments', ?)
11:46:43.610 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - update SurrogateKeys set KeyValue = ? where KeyValue = ? and TableName = 'Departments'
11:46:43.612 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select KeyValue from SurrogateKeys where TableName = 'Departments' for update
11:46:43.612 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - update SurrogateKeys set KeyValue = ? where KeyValue = ? and TableName = 'Departments'
11:46:43.613 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identifier: 1, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator
11:46:43.613 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
11:46:43.613 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@67b355c8]
11:46:43.613 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - committing
11:46:43.613 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
11:46:43.614 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections
11:46:43.614 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
11:46:43.614 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
11:46:43.614 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
11:46:43.614 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - edu.ucdavis.dss.dw.entities.Department{courses=null, code=null, name=null, id=1}
11:46:43.620 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.resourceloading.PlatformResourceBundleLocator - ValidationMessages not found.
11:46:43.624 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.resourceloading.PlatformResourceBundleLocator - org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages found.
11:46:43.637 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - rolling back
11:46:43.638 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - rolled JDBC Connection
11:46:43.638 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - re-enabling autocommit
11:46:43.639 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@67b355c8] after transaction
11:46:43.640 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
11:46:43.648 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Releasing JDBC connection
11:46:43.649 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Released JDBC connection
11:46:43.649 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Resuming suspended transaction after completion of inner transaction
11:46:43.651 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
11:46:43.651 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@3a90c13c]
11:46:43.651 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - rolling back
11:46:43.651 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - rolled JDBC Connection
11:46:43.651 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - re-enabling autocommit
11:46:43.652 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@3a90c13c] after transaction
11:46:43.652 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
11:46:43.652 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl - HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
11:46:43.652 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Releasing JDBC connection
11:46:43.653 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Released JDBC connection
11:46:43.655 [main] DEBUG com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener - Skipping @DatabaseTest expectation due to test exception class org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException
11:46:43.656 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSourceConnection - close() - start
11:46:43.657 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@1da2cb77 testClass = BannerManagerTestCase, testInstance = edu.ucdavis.dss.dw.site.BannerManagerTestCase@48f278eb, testMethod = testCatchesNullDepartment@BannerManagerTestCase, testException = org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@2f217633 testClass = BannerManagerTestCase, locations = '{}', classes = '{class edu.ucdavis.dss.dw.config.TestContextConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class dirties context [false], class mode [null], method dirties context [false].
11:46:43.675 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@1da2cb77 testClass = BannerManagerTestCase, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@2f217633 testClass = BannerManagerTestCase, locations = '{}', classes = '{class edu.ucdavis.dss.dw.config.TestContextConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], dirtiesContext [false].
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.299 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Tests in error: 
  testCatchesNullDepartment(edu.ucdavis.dss.dw.site.BannerManagerTestCase): Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
```

If I'm not sure if I'm reading that correctly -- I see the null-valued department entity and then the information that it is rolling back but one would think it would indicate somewhere as to why it decided to rollback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run the problematic method in a new transaction. Instead of `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)`, you should use [Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRES_NEW):

`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`

to force the creation of a new transaction. `NOT_SUPPORTED` does not lead to the creation of a new transaction, it only suspends the current one.

Wrap the call to the method in a try/catch block. I am not sure what Exception you are going to get in a spring environment. In Java EE, it would be `EJBException`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to change the error. I've set it to REQUIRES_NEW and updated the original question to include the log.

Comment: You were right, I had an additional repository call in the same transaction that was altering the results.

Comment: this looks perfect but remember the outer transaction(on failure) will not rollback the changes made in inner transaction.

Comment: true, I have not handled the inverse case.